# makefile - How to read three element list?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Below is the code, that capture tag arguments:

```
.PHONY: tag

tag:
    ${INFO} "Tag image with tags $(LIST_ARGS)..."
    # use a, b, c

ifeq (tag, $(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    LIST_ARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)), $(MAKECMDGOALS))
    ifeq ($(LIST_ARGS),)
        $(error You must specify a tag)
    endif
    $(eval $(LIST_ARGS):;@:)  # # Do not interpret "tag" arguments as make target files
    # Copy three element list to variables a, b & c 
endif
```

---

On running `make tag 1.1 44 ds23`,

`LIST_ARGS` stores values `1.1 44 ds23`

`a` should store `1.1`

`b` should store `44`

`c` should store `ds23`

---

How to read each value from this `$(LIST_ARGS)` and store in separate variable `a`, `b` & `c` respectively? within task `tag`

Comment: You're asking one (compound) question, and implying few strange things. *Make* variables and *shell* variables are different things. Which do you want?

Comment: @Beta Am asking for *Make* variables `a`, `b`, `c`. For example: `LIST_ARGS` is *Make* variable

Comment: Then why do you want to make the assignment within a *rule?* Do you mean that you want those variables to have those values within that rule and not outside it?

Comment: @Beta I want to use those three variables in `tag` target. This is the Goal. Updated query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem:

```
a := $(word 1, $(LIST_ARGS))
b := $(word 2, $(LIST_ARGS))
c := $(word 3, $(LIST_ARGS))

tag:
    ...
```

(In case this doesn't satisfy you, we can discus the question further.)